# How do you display a vertical scrollbar on the .NET WebBrowser control only when it's needed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Unlike say a RichTextBox control which has a enum ScrollBars property, the WebBrowser control just has a boolean property "ScrollBarsEnabled".

Setting it ScrollBarsEnabled = True, the vertical scrollbar shows all the time (even when not needed).  The horizontal scrollbar behaves as one would expect and only appears when it's needed.

Setting ScrollBarsEnabled = False; 
neither scrollbar ever shows up.

### Sample Code:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();

        webBrowser1.Size = new Size(this.Width - 50, this.Height - 50);
        webBrowser1.Location = new Point(25, 10);
        webBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;
        webBrowser1.ScrollBarsEnabled = true;

        string preText = "<html><head></head><body><div>";
        string bodyText = "Hello World";
        string postText = "</body></div></html>";
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = preText + bodyText + postText;


        this.Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
    }
```

[image: Output of code sample, notice the vertical scrollbar]

Other things tried:

- Tried in .Net 4.0, & .Net 2.0.
- Tried with computers that had IE6 and IE8
- Tried loading an external page (using .Navigate("someurl") instead of setting DocumentText.

Comment: No repro.  Consider updating your version of IE.

Comment: @Hans Passant, Same effect whether IE6 or IE8 is installed on the machine.  Tried .net 2.0 & 4.0.  Also tried .Navigate("someurl") instead of generating my own HTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scroll bars can be controlled in most browsers via CSS, though useful only if you have control of the content:

```
html, body
{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Of course, whether the WebBrowser control honours this is yet to be seen.

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: It Worked!!! I was definitely thinking about this problem in a Windows Forms kind of way and not a web way.  I would have never guessed that!  Thanks!

Comment: Just did the same from a C++ MFC route! Thank you Will.